# QEMU/KVM Windows 11 Code 52 error with display driver

Tags: virtualization

I am trying to run a W11 VM and the VM is working OK but I cannot get the display driver from virtio-win-0.1.248.iso to be accepted.
The message I have from the Red Hat driver Properties is:-

Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52).

I have wasted many hours trying to sort this out but most of the suggested options either do not apply to a VM or solutions are ephemeral and once VM is shit down and later started the repairs no longer work.

I know others will have come across this but is there a reliable solution please?